# How do I view information on the peers my Bitcoin Core full node is connected to?

Tags: bitcoin-core, p2p

I would like to view information on the peers my Bitcoin Core full node is connected to. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 0xB10C posts [here](https://twitter.com/0xB10C/status/1305779659523543040?s=20) you can get a peer dashboard to bitcoin-cli that looks like this.

[image: netinfo dashboard]

You can get this dashboard by using

```
watch ./src/bitcoin-cli -netinfo 4
```

and you can use the `-asmap` flag too.

This netinfo feature was [merged](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/19643) into Bitcoin Core in September 2020 and is included in the release of Bitcoin Core version 0.21 . (The feature was built by Jon Atack.)

Additional guidance for using this feature was added in this [PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/20829).