# How can I use Bitcoin Core with the anonymous network protocol I2P?

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor, p2p, i2p

How can I use Bitcoin Core with the I2P anonymous network protocol?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jon Atack answered this on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/jonatack/status/1366764964896075776?s=20).

**Configuration and setup**

First install and start I2P (version 2.35 or above).

```
$ apt install i2pd
$ systemctl enable i2pd.service
$ systemctl start i2pd.service
```

In your `bitcoin.conf` file add (I will assume you run Bitcoin Core v22+ and want to use both Tor and I2P but remove `debug=tor` and `onlynet=onion` if not interested in Tor):

```
debug=tor
debug=i2p
onlynet=onion
onlynet=i2p
i2psam=127.0.0.1:7656
```

There are 2 config options for I2P. Only the second one is required to be set for I2P to work.

```
  -i2pacceptincoming
       If set and -i2psam is also set then incoming I2P connections are
       accepted via the SAM proxy. If this is not set but -i2psam is set
       then only outgoing connections will be made to the I2P network.
       Ignored if -i2psam is not set. Listening for incoming I2P
       connections is done through the SAM proxy, not by binding to a
       local address and port (default: 1)

  -i2psam=<ip:port>
       I2P SAM proxy to reach I2P peers and accept I2P connections (default:
       none)
```

**Connecting to I2P peers**

There are some hardcoded I2P seeds at the bottom of this [file](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/seeds/nodes_main.txt) to get started with connections. Scroll down to `# manually added 2021-05 for minimal i2p bootstrap support`

You can connect to these seeds with `-addnode` or `-seednode` in your configuration file (`bitcoin.conf`).

(If your `peers.dat` is empty and you start up with `-dnsseed=0` then your node will only know the hardcoded seeds.)

Once you have connections you can view your I2P peers:

`watch -t ./src/bitcoin-cli -netinfo 4`

(For more information on `-netinfo` see the help documentation using `bitcoin-cli -netinfo help` or this StackExchange [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99064/how-do-i-view-information-on-the-peers-my-bitcoin-core-full-node-is-connected-to/))

[image]

This was enabled by Vasil Dimov's Bitcoin Core [PR 20685](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/20685) merged in March 2021 and [BIP 155](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0155.mediawiki) for addrv2 messages

Historical discussion of supporting I2P back in 2012 is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2091). (Thanks to Adam Jonas for finding this)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It will be helpful if you could review a PR which has a part that may include [few things](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21157#discussion_r585734181) about i2p: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21157

Comment: when I try to start the service, I get "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."

Comment: what is the "4" for on the watch command?

Comment: @Rebroad: See Jon Atack's pull https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/20829 "4 - Like 1 but with both address and version columns". Basically 4 provides the most information that is possible for netinfo whilst 0 provides the least.

Comment: @Rebroad: Re your error message. Are you running bitcoind before you run the watch command? If you are I don't know why you are getting that error message. Feel free to ask about it on Freenode #bitcoin-core-pr-reviews

Comment: @nisc: It hasn't been released yet as part of v22.0 of Bitcoin Core and thus far these are the only instructions to do it so it is still early :) I think the nodes should get picked up by Bitnodes but I'll check

Comment: @MichaelFolkson now that I2P is live in an official release, do you know if there's a place to track the growth of the I2P network? Does BitNodes support it?

Comment: found that adding `onlynet=i2p` stopped the node from making successful i2p connections.
My additions to bitcoin.conf:  
`debug=tor`  
`debug=i2p`  
`i2psam=127.0.0.1:7656`  
`i2pacceptincoming=1`  

The full manual process of installing i2p fro bitcoin on a RaspiBlitz:
https://github.com/rootzoll/raspiblitz/issues/2413#issuecomment-1013855483